# Javascript read textfile and safe every row in his own variable

Tags: javascript, html, text-files

I need your help. I want to safe every row of a textfile in his own Variable with Javascript.
**How do I read text out of a text file?

How do I safe every row in his own variable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use an array like the following code shows you:

```
var file = new XMLHttpRequest();
file.open("GET", "test.txt", false);
file.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if(file.readyState === 4 && (file.status === 200 || file.status == 0))
    {
        var rows= file.responseText.split("\n");
        alert(rows[1]);
    }
}
file.send(null);
```

"test.txt" is the full path to the txt file and rows[0] contains the row 1.
split("\n") creates an array with every row stored as an entry. you can use rows[n] to get a specific row.

Comment: Thank you very much